# change a a list inside a string to a java String[]

Tags: java, string, list

I have a string containing a list and by that I mean :

```
String list = "[\"hello\",\"everyone\"]";
```

How can I transform that so I can read it as a `String[]`? My question might not be very clear but please understand English is not my native language thanks everyone.

Comment: The string looks like JSON -- is it? If so, you should use a JSON parser. That way it will also handle escape characters within the string for you.

Comment: @yshavit Its actually a javascript script that I am reading as string and from which I would like to extract this list :/

Comment: JSON is a subset of JavaScript, so if you're sure the script only contains a list of arrays -- or if you already know how to isolate just that substring of the script -- then a JSON parser will still work.

Comment: @yshavit I will give that a try thanks for your proposal :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `replace` and `split` methods of `String` class, e.g.:

```
String s = "[\"hello\",\"everyone\"]";
String[] split = s.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        String [] strArray = new String [] {"hello","everyone"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Imports:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
```

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "[\"hello\",\"everyone\"]"; // This is the input String
    input = input.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\\", "").replace("\"", ""); // Remove
                                                                                            // the
                                                                                            // following
                                                                                            // characters:
                                                                                            // [
                                                                                            // ]
                                                                                            // \
                                                                                            // "
    String splitOn = ", "; // The string will split whenever this pattern
                            // occurs
    List<String> output = Arrays.asList(input.split(splitOn)); // Split on
                                                                // the
                                                                // String
    System.out.println(output); // Output the result
}
```

**Output:**

```
[hello,everyone]
```